# How can I check which observers are enable in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, observer-pattern, observers

I have different observers enabled in different enviroments and I would like to be able to check which are enabled via console

Something like

```
ActiveRecord::Observers.list
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do it via `ActiveRecord::Base.observers`.

Answer (score -1):

Try `ActiveRecord::Observer.observed_classes`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it simply prints "activerecord".  ActiveRecord::Base.observers works